# iPhone: Login Screen image that fit all iPhone screens as of now

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimage, fullscreen

I've been researching this and I got different answers. I want to create a login screen image that fits all the current iPhone screens. This image will take up the whole iPhone screen. What is the best way accomplishing this? Should I make separate images for each iPhone screen? Or is there a better way? I am very confused on what is best practice.

What size does the @2x and @3x need to be?

Comment: You can make one big image (with @2x and @3x), and center it on the screen.

Comment: What size is @2x and @3x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create the different images for each screen it will give you the better result with pixels. (You have more content on login screen then choose this option)
Otherwise create the one image and use the auto layout or size class to make it looks good.

@2x and @3x is for notations to size.

Comment: What size is @2x and @3x?

Comment: If you give name the iphone 5 screen size as image.png then give the name iphone 6 as image@2x.png and iphone 6s as image@3x.png.

Answer (score 0):

Since your image will take up whole iPhone screen frame, you might thinking of using Auto layout constraint which will resize/fix your image based on iPhones' frame as better approach. useful link that you can refer:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/BuildingforMultipleScreenSizes.html

and for the size you can refer:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html